# Splitting Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe that contains timestamps and I am looking for a way to batch multiple rows together based on whether their timestamp is within a 1 minute interval of the next and previous entry. I know I could probably iterate over each row and do a straightforward comparison, though I am looking for a faster way to do it. Rows of the dataframe are sorted based on time.

To rephrase, I want each batch to satisfy the following property: No timestamp of a row is more than 1 min apart from any adjacent row (previous and next). How could I transform the code above to make it faster?

Comment: can you provide the code? Can you give us an [mcve]?

Comment: @pythonic833 Edited the question and provided the code that does exactly what I want but inefficiently.

Comment: this is no [mcve], please provide the code on how to generate `data`.

Comment: @pythonic833 I think I finally got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
data['batch'] = data.time.transform(lambda x: x - x.shift() > pd.Timedelta('1m')).cumsum()

         time                     batch
0   2020-06-29 16:47:34.325726420   0
1   2020-06-29 16:47:55.871976370   0
2   2020-06-29 16:48:53.704053189   0
3   2020-06-29 16:49:41.253228187   0
4   2020-06-29 16:50:42.870308699   1
5   2020-06-29 16:50:46.870308699   1
6   2020-06-29 16:51:30.870318699   1
7   2020-06-29 16:52:32.830308699   2
```

Explanation: Assuming the `time` column is sorted we compare each value with the next and check whether the distance is larger than one minute. Using `cumsum` sums the booleans to return the batch number.

Comment: Try this (shorter and slightly faster): `data['batch'] = (data['time'].diff() > pd.Timedelta('1m')).cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas.date_range` method might be what you are looking for: [see the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Comment: That doesn't do what I want. See the example above.